# Azure alert when Resource Health becomes unavailable or available

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Does Azure provide any alert that simply tells me if my Virtual Network or any other resource health is Up(available) or Down(unavailable). I am not talking about Service Level health which is region specific. I am talking about resource level health.
I looked at the list of alerts here and its not available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics

I see a lot of Alerting options, but availability does not show up here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-near-real-time-metric-alerts#metrics-and-dimensions-supported

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-near-real-time-metric-alerts

Comment: Could you try https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msoms/2016/09/08/how-to-generate-an-alert-in-microsoft-oms-when-a-computer-is-down-or-unreachable/

Comment: Thanks, this gives health details related to VM, i want health alert for all the resources, in the Azure Portal we can see a section called "Resource health", but can we create an Alert for this?

Comment: try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts-on-service-notifications

Comment: This is for a region i need for a particular resource.

Comment: If you are open to 3rd party products, look into CloudMonix @ https://www.cloudmonix.com -- this basic and many other advanced scenarios are available by default in its monitoring templates.  Specifically, CloudMonix can alert on outage of any connections inside of an Azure VPN Gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the activity logs which is on a subscription level. You can create alerts on resource types and on specific category of alerts (Alert, Service Health , Security 
 , recommendations etc.)

More info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs#what-you-can-do-with-the-activity-log

Comment: Activity Logs tells you about the external events that happens to your resource, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit

Comment: This helps. Thanks